# How to enable horizontal scroll in tab like Google Play?

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, android-support-design

I'm referencing a great [demo here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) regarding material design. It has tabs, but when I add too many the tab items get squished (see screenshot). How can I make it scroll horizontally?

[image]

I believe below is the layout I should make the change, but I combed the docs and can't seem to get it, pls help!

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try put your `TabLayout` in `HorizontalScrollingView`?

Comment: hey @N1to that worked! Pls leave as an answer and I'll accept. I just wrapped the `TabLayout` with `<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="match_parent">`. Only thing is when I swipe to a tab off the screen, it doesn't focus on that tab.

Comment: Don't do that, TabLayout itself is already an HorizontalScrollview. You should set the TabLayout in MODE_SCROLLABLE (it's in the docs)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

`TabLayout` has a method [`setTabMode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setTabMode%28int%29) which can be either `MODE_FIXED` (default) or `MODE_SCROLLABLE` which is what you need.

You can also define this in XML with `app:tabMode="scrollable"`.

Comment: refer to this blog for a demo http://www.ekiras.com/2015/12/how-to-implement-material-design-tab-layout-in-android.html

Comment: In my case I use TabLayout in left. Is it possible to scroll in vertical?

Answer (score 5):

You can add this `app:tabMode="scrollable"` to your `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`

Comment: What is difference between your and accepted Answer ?

Answer (score 2):

If you added

```
app:tabMode="scrollable"
```

like mentioned above and it,

> shows the layout and you are not able to scroll

Then maybe you have put it at the top of the XML file and below it added `matchh_parent` (height/width) to the ViewPager. Because the viewpager is above the tab layout you will not be able to scroll.
Add it at the bottom of the XML so another view does to overlap the tab layout.

Answer (score 0):

SlidingTabLayout and SlidingTabStrip classes is what are you looking for
You need to copy these classes from google developers site, add sliding tab layout in xml, and in set viewpager for sliding tab layout in java. Hope it'll help.

Comment: I'm finding example of how to make this from scratch, is this not a native control?

Comment: As far I know its not included in library, but there is a source code of this controls. https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html You need to copy them to your project.