# How to create horizontal scroll buttons below tabs like playstore android

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, tabview

[here the image i want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iArU.jpg)sorry for asking this basic question .I  search in google but no solution , i'm new to android i develop tabs like latest google play store i did that part but i want design horizontal scroll button below the tab like play store any one please help me how to do this .thank you in advance

here below my layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/music"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                bind:height_aspect_ratio="@{4f/3}"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                >

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <com.chanti.engapp.widget.SearchBoxCompat
                android:id="@+id/search_box"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-48dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:foreground="@android:color/transparent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/current_item"
        layout="@layout/fragment_item_tab"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

here my tabs code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs_layout, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    LVRecentlyViewed.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    contentList.clear();
    objects = ResultFragment.categoryDtoList.get(ResultFragment.viewPager.getCurrentItem()).getSubCategoryList();

    if (ResultFragment.adapter.getPageTitle(ResultFragment.viewPager.getCurrentItem()).equals("FilmNews")) {
        ResultFragment.IVImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.film);
    } else if (ResultFragment.adapter.getPageTitle(ResultFragment.viewPager.getCurrentItem()).equals("Videos")) {
        ResultFragment.IVImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.video);
    } else if (ResultFragment.adapter.getPageTitle(ResultFragment.viewPager.getCurrentItem()).equals("Music")) {
        ResultFragment.IVImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.music);
    } else {
        ResultFragment.IVImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.film);
    }

    getContentList();

    mAdapter = new RecentlyViewedListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.card_item2, contentList);

    LVRecentlyViewed.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //date sorting in onstart







    RecyclerItemClickSupport.addTo(LVRecentlyViewed).setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
            chosenItem = contentList.get(position);
            if (!pageTitle.toString().equals("Movies")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsVideosAndMusicActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("choseItem", chosenItem);
                intent.putExtra("title",""+ResultFragment.viewPager.getCurrentItem());
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsMovesActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            request();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
private void request() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Processing");
    progressDialog.show();
    ChantiApplication.getService().retrieveList().enqueue(new Callback<List<CategoryDto>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<CategoryDto>> call, Response<List<CategoryDto>> response) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            progressDialog.hide();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                contentList.clear();
                ResultFragment.categoryDtoList = response.body();
                objects = ResultFragment.categoryDtoList.get(ResultFragment.viewPager.getCurrentItem()).getSubCategoryList();

                if (ResultFragment.adapter.getPageTitle(ResultFragment.viewPager.getCurrentItem()).equals("FilmNews")) {
                    ResultFragment.IVImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.film);
                } else if (ResultFragment.adapter.getPageTitle(ResultFragment.viewPager.getCurrentItem()).equals("Videos")) {
                    ResultFragment.IVImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.video);
                } else if (ResultFragment.adapter.getPageTitle(ResultFragment.viewPager.getCurrentItem()).equals("Music")) {
                    ResultFragment.IVImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.music);
                } else {
                    ResultFragment.IVImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.film);
                }

                getContentList();

                mAdapter = new RecentlyViewedListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.card_item2, contentList);
                LVRecentlyViewed.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else {
                ResponseDto error = ErrorUtils.parseError(response);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getError(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<CategoryDto>> call, Throwable t) {
            //  Log.d("error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    LVRecentlyViewed.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    contentList.clear();
    objects = ResultFragment.categoryDtoList.get(ResultFragment.viewPager.getCurrentItem()).getSubCategoryList();

    if (ResultFragment.adapter.getPageTitle(ResultFragment.viewPager.getCurrentItem()).equals("FilmNews")) {
        ResultFragment.IVImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.film);
    } else if (ResultFragment.adapter.getPageTitle(ResultFragment.viewPager.getCurrentItem()).equals("Videos")) {
        ResultFragment.IVImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.video);
    } else if (ResultFragment.adapter.getPageTitle(ResultFragment.viewPager.getCurrentItem()).equals("Music")) {
        ResultFragment.IVImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.music);
    } else {
        ResultFragment.IVImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.film);
    }

    getContentList();

    mAdapter = new RecentlyViewedListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.card_item2, contentList);
    LVRecentlyViewed.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //date sorting in onstart

    Collections.sort(contentList, new Comparator<SubCategory>() {

        public int compare(SubCategory o1, SubCategory o2) {
            if (o1.getCreateDate() == null || o2.getCreateDate() == null)
                return 0;
            return o2.getCreateDate().compareTo(o1.getCreateDate());
        }
    });

}

private void getContentList()
{

    contentList.clear();
    pageTitle = ResultFragment.adapter.getPageTitle(ResultFragment.viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    ArrayList<String> checkedSubCat = CheckListActivity.checkedSubCateg.get(pageTitle);
    if (checkedSubCat != null) {
        for (String subCategoryName : checkedSubCat) {
            for (SubCategory object : objects) {
                if (subCategoryName.equals(object.getSubCategoryName())) {
                    for (SubCategory contentItem : object.getContentList()) {
                        contentList.add(contentItem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Checked",0);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = preferences.getString("checkedSubCategory", "");
        if(json!=null) {
            CategoryListDto categoryListDto = gson.fromJson(json, CategoryListDto.class);
            if(categoryListDto!=null) {
                ArrayList<String> checkedCategory = categoryListDto.getCheckedSubCateg().get(pageTitle);
                for (String subCategoryName : checkedCategory) {
                    for (SubCategory object : objects) {
                        if (subCategoryName.equals(object.getSubCategoryName())) {
                            for (SubCategory contentItem : object.getContentList()) {
                                contentList.add(contentItem);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(contentList, new Comparator<SubCategory>() {
        public int compare(SubCategory o1, SubCategory o2) {
            if (o1.getCreateDate() == null || o2.getCreateDate() == null)
                return 0;
            return o2.getCreateDate().compareTo(o1.getCreateDate());
        }
    });

}

public void getChoosenItem(int position) {
    chosenItem = contentList.get(position);
}
```

}

Comment: use horizontal recycler view..

Comment: i am asking about only button not recylerview ,i point out in image please check once thank u@Sabish.M

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194199/how-to-enable-horizontal-scroll-in-tab-like-google-play see this link........ Use the demo of question and fuctionality to answer

Answer (score 1):

```
      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#fff">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="abc"
                    android:background="#ff0000" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="abc"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:background="#00ff00"
                 />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="abc"
                    android:background="#ff0000" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="abc"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:background="#00ff00"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="abc"
                    android:background="#ff0000" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="abc"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:background="#00ff00"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           try {

            int height, width;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LinearLayout subslytlnr = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            subslytlnr.setLayoutParams(params);
            subslytlnr.setPadding(0, 12, 0, 12);
            HorizontalScrollView scrollViewSubscribeBtn;
            scrollViewSubscribeBtn = new HorizontalScrollView(getActivity());
            scrollViewSubscribeBtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            scrollViewSubscribeBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.actionbartop);
            subsButton = new Button[numOf Buttons];

            for (int i = 0; i < numOf Buttons; i++) {

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsBtn;
                width = (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.subsbuttonheight) / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
                height = (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.subsbuttonwidth) / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

                    paramsBtn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 40);
                    paramsBtn.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);


                subsButton[i] = new Button(getActivity());

               subsButton[i].setTextSize(20);

                subsButton[i].setLayoutParams(paramsBtn);

                subsButton[i].setText("button"+i+"");
                subsButton[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
                subslytlnr.addView(subsButton[i]);
                subsButton[i].setOnClickListener(myClickListener3);
            }
            scrollViewSubscribeBtn.addView(subslytlnr);
            subsaBtnLayout.addView(scrollViewSubscribeBtn);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrollable_tabs);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager2(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new            ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new feature_fragment(), "Feature");
    adapter.addFrag(new service_fragment(), "Service");
    adapter.addFrag(new contact_fragment(), "Contact");
    adapter.addFrag(new login_fragment(), "Login");
    adapter.addFrag(new about_fragment(), "About");
    adapter.addFrag(new casi_certification_fragment(), "CASI Certification");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: I'm asking about horizontal scroll button only please look my code i edited my post thank u@Saurabh Bhardwaj

Comment: these tabs can scroll.

Comment: Yes my tabs are scroll i need horizontal scroll button  below tabs ,like play store thank u @Saurabh Bhardwaj

Comment: Are you want horizontal scroll button in fragment or xml?

Comment: you can try in fragment.xml