# android how to scroll BottomNavigationView with Fragment Tablayout ViewPager in side Fragment RecyclerView Scroll toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

android `BottomNavigationView` with `ViewPager` implement `Fragment` and `fragment` inside `tablayout` attached with `ViewPager` `Fragment` `RecyclerView` `Scroll Toolbar scroll`

if `RecyclerView` `Scroll toolbar scroll` Please help me

As like this image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add `TabLayout` with `PagerView` by following step:

**Step 1:**
Add layout into you main xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:tabStripEnabled="true"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"// make a xml selector
        app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#ff727272"
        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Step 2:**
Find these into your `Activity` and set FragmentPagerAdapter into PagerView and set other properties like this

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Artcles"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Dicussion"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("News"));



ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);

ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        fragments.add(new ArtclesFragment());// create an ArtclesFragment 
        fragments.add(new DicussionFragment());// Create a DicussionFragment 
        fragments.add(new NewsFragment());   //Create a NewsFragment
 mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragPagerAdaptor(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments););



  mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

**FragPagerAdaptor look like:**

```
public class FragPagerAdaptor extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;

public FragPagerAdaptor(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments == null ? 0 : fragments.size();
}
}
```

**Note:** You have to create separate `fragemet` for each tab.

Hope it help you understand basic implementation of Tab and `PagerView` `TabLayout`.

Comment: i want to RecyclerView scroll Toolbar scroll

Comment: You can also set app:tabMode="scrollable" to scroll tab https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194199/how-to-enable-horizontal-scroll-in-tab-like-google-play

Comment: or can create custom tab https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601414/tablayout-not-filling-width-when-tabmode-set-to-scrollable

Comment: i want to this type of layout be behaviour see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEhdS.gif